# How to convert [i8; 88] to something stringy

Tags: string, rust, ffi

I have a `bytes: [i8; 88]` (88 just for example, but you might see where it comes from).  Supposedly this is `bytes` representation of `utf-8 string`.  For additional twist, this `array` might be non nul-terminated.  What is the most idiomatic way to convert this `object` to `native Rust string (String ?)?` Same question, but for the most cheap way, e.g. with no memory allocations or any other criteria.

My first naive attempt as the person only starting to learn the language:

```
fn statfs_get_mntonname(s: &statfs) -> String {
    let mut v_mntonname: std::vec::Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..88 {
        v_mntonname.push(s.f_mntonname[i] as u8)
    }
    v_mntonname.push(0);
    let c_mnttoname = unsafe { CStr::from_bytes_with_nul_unchecked(
        v_mntonname.as_ref()) };
    (*c_mnttoname.to_string_lossy()).to_string()
}
```

Comment: _"For additional twist, this array might be non nul-terminated"_ if it is nul-terminated, you have to remove the last byte before converting it to a string.

Comment: _"I have a bytes: `[i8; 88]`"_ I'm curious, why do you have bytes stored as `i8` (signed integers)? `i8` is intended only for values that can be negative.

Comment: This is a syscall interface, kernel can return the string non-terminated if its length is exactly 88 bytes.  Why it is i8, I do not know, this is how rust libc defines the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you look for [`from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) or its unsafe cousin [`from_utf8_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html).

Comment: from_utf8 takes slice [u8], while I have [i8; <fixed size>] array

Comment: from_utf8 takes slice (i.e. pair pointer,size), I have array that is, just a bytes in memory.  Is there some additional magic to convert one to another ?

Comment: E.g. like this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc6a6cb369196100deb498e8540624d0 - to avoid unsafe, copy bytewise into an `u8` Vec/array, converting i8 to u8.

Comment: @phimuemue it can be written in IMHO clearer way by using `&my_array[..]` - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd409c8714b29d73108e907461ad87b0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @phimuemue, the following solves my needs:

```
fn mnt_to_string(bytes: &[i8]) -> String {
   unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(std::mem::transmute(bytes)) }.to_string()
}

fn statfs_get_fstypename(s: &statfs) -> String {
     mnt_to_string(&s.f_fstypename as &[i8])
}
```